Index out of range in linear regression(The Boston Model)
Here we are trying to train a linear regression model on Boston data sheet.Although the data sheet is unavailable in the latest versions of Scikit library, we can use it by the code in line 7 and line 8.
It is saying that the index is out of bounds
I thought it would be due to the permutation got out of range in permute_data function created b us so in the next line I had put X[perm-1] instead of X[perm] same was done with y; Yet the problem persists, The code is as follows(Sorry it is lengthy,So I would need a part of your time):
import numpy as np
from numpy import ndarray
from typing import Tuple
from typing import Dict
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml 
boston = fetch_openml(name='boston', version=1) 
data = boston['data']
target = boston['target']
features = boston['feature_names']
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
s = StandardScaler()
data = s.fit_transform(data)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(data,target,test_size=0.30,random_state= 80718)
y_train = np.reshape(-1,1)
y_test = np.reshape(-1,1)
def init_weights(rows):
    W = np.random.randn(rows,1)
    B = np.random.randn(1,1) # Try with B as only integer
    weights = {}
    weights['W'] = W
    weights['B'] = B
    return weights
def linear_forward(X_batch:ndarray,y_batch:ndarray,weights: Dict[str,ndarray]) -> Tuple[float,dict[str,ndarray]]:
    d  = np.dot(X_batch,weights['W'])
    P :ndarray = d + weights['B']
    loss = np.mean(np.power(y_batch - P,2))
    forward_info :Dict[str,ndarray]= {}
    forward_info['X'] = X_batch
    forward_info['N'] = d
    forward_info['P'] = P
    forward_info['y'] = y_batch
    return forward_info, loss
def loss_gradients(forward_info:Dict[str,ndarray],weights:Dict[str,ndarray]):
    dLdP = -1*2*(forward_info['y'] - forward_info['P'])
    dPdW = np.transpose(forward_info['X'])
    dLdW = np.dot(dPdW,dLdP)
    dPdB = np.ones_like(weights['B'])
    dLdB = (dLdP * dPdB).sum(axis = 0)
    loss_gradients :Dict[str,ndarray]= {}
    loss_gradients['W'] = dLdW # Change of loss with respect to our functions 
    loss_gradients['B'] = dLdB 
    return loss_gradients
def generate_batch(X:ndarray,y:ndarray,start,batch_size): # Yekda nusta return last X[last] karun baghu
    assert X.ndim == y.ndim == 2
    if start + batch_size > X.shape[0]:
        batch_size = X.shape[0] - start
    X_batch,y_batch = X[start: start+batch_size],y[start:start+batch_size]
    return X_batch,y_batch 
def permute_data(X:ndarray,y:ndarray):
    perm = np.random.permutation(X.shape[0])
    return X[perm],y[perm]
def train(X:ndarray,y:ndarray,n_iter,batch_size,learning_rate,return_weights:bool,seed):
    if seed:                    # ......................nahi kalaala
        np.random.seed(seed)
    start = 0 # Nahi kalaala
    weights = init_weights(X.shape[1])
    X,y = permute_data(X,y)
    losses = []
    for i in range(n_iter):
        if start >= X.shape[0]:
            X,y = permute_data(X,y)
            start = 0
        X_batch,y_batch = generate_batch(X,y,start,batch_size)
        start+=batch_size # start = start + batch_size
        forward_info,loss = linear_forward(X_batch,y_batch,weights)
        losses.append(loss)
        loss_grads = loss_gradients(forward_info,weights)
        for key in weights.keys():
            weights[key] -= learning_rate*loss_grads[key]
    if return_weights:
        return losses,weights
train_info = train(X_train,y_train,1000,23,0.001,True,80718) #Seeds Badlun Baghu
losses = train_info[0]
weights_trained = train_info[1]
plt.plot(list(range(1000)), losses)
def predict(X: ndarray,weights:Dict[str,ndarray]): #weights to be put here are the ones obtained from training
    N = np.dot(X,weights['W'])
    P = N + weights['B']
    return P
preds = predict(X_test,weights_trained)
def mae(preds: ndarray, actuals: ndarray):
    return np.mean(np.abs(preds - actuals))
def rmsE(preds:ndarray,actuals:ndarray):
    return np .sqrt(np.mean(np.power(actuals - preds,2)))
print("Mean absolute error:", round(mae(preds, y_test), 4), 
      "Root mean squared error:", round(rmsE(preds, y_test), 4))\
'''
The error is as follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Documents/Code/Deep Learning/hu.py", line 75, in <module>
    train_info = train(X_train,y_train,1000,23,0.001,True,80718) #Seeds Badlun Baghu
  File "Documents/Code/Deep Learning/hu.py", line 60, in train
    X,y = permute_data(X,y)
  File "Documents/Code/Deep Learning/hu.py", line 54, in permute_data
    return X[perm],y[perm]
IndexError: index 188 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
'''


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Could you show the full stack trace of the error?  Also, if you add a couple of print statements in permute_data(), what is the value of perm when the error occurs? Does the error always happen when permute_data() is called, or only sometimes?
Maybe try adding a try/except block in permute_data()  to try and get those return values, and return them if successfuly, otherwise log the relevant data and force quit when an index error occurs?  At least for debugging purposes - it wouldn't have to be a permanent code change.

@nigh_anxiety  Yes it always happens.This is the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Documents/Code/Deep Learning/hu.py", line 75, in 
train_info = train(X_train,y_train,1000,23,0.001,True,80718) #Seeds Badlun Baghu
File "Documents/Code/Deep Learning/hu.py", line 60, in train
X,y = permute_data(X,y)
File "Documents/Code/Deep Learning/hu.py", line 54, in permute_data
return X[perm],y[perm]
IndexError: index 188 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

The main issue seems to be the incorrect usage of np.reshape(). In your code, you've done the following (in PyCharm, it immediately highlights a linter warning with the message Redeclared {'y_train', 'y_test'} above without usage):
y_train = np.reshape(-1,1)
y_test = np.reshape(-1,1)

This should be:
y_train = np.reshape(y_train, (-1,1))
y_test = np.reshape(y_test, (-1,1))

Secondly, a few type-hinting issues too. Your return type hint for the definition of linear_forward(); Tuple[float,dict[str,ndarray]] is not in the correct order as they are being returned by the function. Furthermore, this throws type error in some Python versions. The correct return type hint should be Tuple[Dict[str, ndarray], float]. I'll also recommend wrapping np.mean() calls in float() if you don't intend to deal with ndarray.
And lastly, please, space out and format your code properly so it is easier to read, debug, and extend: place all imports at the top; semantically group related code blocks together; or otherwise use an adequate linter. I will recommend going through the official style guide for Python.
Updated Code:
import numpy as np
from numpy import ndarray
from typing import Tuple, Dict
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


boston = fetch_openml(name='boston', version=1)
data = boston['data']
target = boston['target']
features = boston['feature_names']

s = StandardScaler()
data = s.fit_transform(data)

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(data,target,test_size=0.30,random_state= 80718)
y_train = np.reshape(y_train, (-1,1))
y_test = np.reshape(y_test, (-1,1))

def init_weights(rows):
    W = np.random.randn(rows,1)
    B = np.random.randn(1,1) # Try with B as only integer
    weights = {'W': W, 'B': B}
    return weights

def linear_forward(X_batch:ndarray,y_batch:ndarray,weights: Dict[str,ndarray]) -> Tuple[Dict[str, ndarray], float]:
    d  = np.dot(X_batch,weights['W'])
    P :ndarray = d + weights['B']
    loss: float = float(np.mean(np.power(y_batch - P, 2)))
    forward_info :Dict[str,ndarray]= {'X': X_batch, 'N': d, 'P': P, 'y': y_batch}
    return forward_info, loss

def loss_gradients(forward_info:Dict[str,ndarray],weights:Dict[str,ndarray]):
    dLdP = -1*2*(forward_info['y'] - forward_info['P'])
    dPdW = np.transpose(forward_info['X'])
    dLdW = np.dot(dPdW,dLdP)
    dPdB = np.ones_like(weights['B'])
    dLdB = (dLdP * dPdB).sum(axis = 0)
    loss_gradients_ :Dict[str,ndarray]= {'W': dLdW, 'B': dLdB}
    return loss_gradients_

def generate_batch(X:ndarray, y:ndarray, start, batch_size): # Yekda nusta return last X[last] karun baghu
    assert X.ndim == y.ndim == 2
    if start + batch_size > X.shape[0]:
        batch_size = X.shape[0] - start
    X_batch,y_batch = X[start: start+batch_size], y[start:start+batch_size]
    return X_batch,y_batch

def permute_data(X:ndarray, y:ndarray):
    perm = np.random.permutation(X.shape[0])
    return X[perm],y[perm]

def train(X:ndarray,y:ndarray,n_iter,batch_size,learning_rate,return_weights:bool,seed):
    if seed:                    # ......................nahi kalaala
        np.random.seed(seed)
    start = 0 # Nahi kalaala
    weights = init_weights(X.shape[1])
    X,y = permute_data(X,y)
    losses_ = []
    for i in range(n_iter):
        if start >= X.shape[0]:
            X,y = permute_data(X,y)
            start = 0
        X_batch,y_batch = generate_batch(X,y,start,batch_size)
        start+=batch_size # start = start + batch_size
        forward_info,loss = linear_forward(X_batch,y_batch,weights)
        losses_.append(loss)
        loss_grads = loss_gradients(forward_info,weights)
        for key in weights.keys():
            weights[key] -= learning_rate*loss_grads[key]
    if return_weights:
        return losses_,weights

train_info = train(X_train,y_train,1000,23,0.001,True,80718) #Seeds Badlun Baghu
losses = train_info[0]
weights_trained = train_info[1]
plt.plot(list(range(1000)), losses)
plt.show()

def predict(X: ndarray,weights:Dict[str,ndarray]): #weights to be put here are the ones obtained from training
    N = np.dot(X,weights['W'])
    P = N + weights['B']
    return P

preds = predict(X_test,weights_trained)

def mae(preds_: ndarray, actuals: ndarray):
    return float(np.mean(np.abs(preds_ - actuals)))

def rmsE(preds_:ndarray, actuals:ndarray):
    return np.sqrt(np.mean(np.power(actuals - preds_, 2)))

print("Mean absolute error:", round(mae(preds, y_test), 4),
      "Root mean squared error:", round(rmsE(preds, y_test), 4))

Output:

Mean absolute error: 3.5402 Root mean squared error: 5.0413


thank a lot for help;grateful for the guide provided, would make sure it is followed

If this answer solves the problem as desired, please consider marking it as accepted. Cheers.
